# How do I make Package Explorer in Eclipse Indigo display my Android projects?

Tags: android, eclipse, package, explorer

I recently upgraded computers and in the process I upgraded to using Eclipse Indigo to develop Android apps. The problem is that Package Explorer will no longer display my projects for either Android 2.3.3 or Android 3.0. It does however display earlier Android versions (e.g., 2.0 and 2.2) in their respective workspaces.

I've checked, and the SDKs for 2.3.3 and 3.0 are installed, and the application/projects are in the correct workspace. Further complicating the issue is that when I try and "Import" the 2.3.3 or 3.0 applications/projects into their respective workspaces, Eclipse won't allow me to do so because it says they already exist in the workspace.

Anyone seen this behavior before or have any idea how to correct it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like some of your desktop files are corrupted or not recognised by Indigo.  Try moving the folders for the projects out of the workspace folder, and then importing them.